# JAXB SOAP Client outbound message has empty soap body (<soap:body/>)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, tcpdump

I am using a mocked service in SOAP UI as my server side to get a response for a soap request I make from my Java web service client.

My Java web service client forms a proper request but I get below response:

```
03-05-2016 00:03:00,562 |ERROR (pool-4919-thread-1)|REMEDY|TT_CONNECTION|ST_ERROR_Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [urn:XEL:TR-AlarmasCapo/New_Create_Operation_0] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [urn:XEL:TR-AlarmasCapo/New_Create_Operation_0] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have set these parameters to false, still the issue persists:

[image]

I see a proper request in my logs but when I see the tcpdump the request is empty. The  tag is empty:

```
12:05:00.536717 IP portal..60954 > soapui..radan-http: Flags [P.], seq 1:308, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4220848935 ecr 3816244343], length 307
E..g..@.@..K...'...)...........E...sh......
...'.wDwPOST /mockNew_Port_0SoapBinding HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
SOAPAction: "urn:XEL:TR-AlarmasCapo/New_Create_Operation_0"
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.6.8.redhat-7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: soapui:8088
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 175


12:05:00.536889 IP portal..60954 > soapui..radan-http: Flags [P.], seq 308:483, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4220848935 ecr 3816244343], length 175
E.....@.@......'...)...........E...sn......
...'.wDw<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/><soap:Body/></soap:Envelope>
12:05:00.537024 IP soapui..radan-http > portal..60954: Flags [.], ack 308, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3816244343 ecr 4220848935], length 0
E..4.2@.@......)...'.......E.......zFB.....
.wDw...'
12:05:00.537180 IP soapui..radan-http > portal..60954: Flags [.], ack 483, win 130, options [nop,nop,TS val 3816244344 ecr 4220848935], length 0
E..4.3@.@......)...'.......E...h....E......
.wDx...'
12:05:00.557174 IP soapui..radan-http > portal..60954: Flags [P.], seq 1:517, ack 483, win 130, options [nop,nop,TS val 3816244364 ecr 4220848935], length 516
E..8.4@.@......)...'.......E...h...........
.wD....'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)

177
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [urn:XEL:TR-AlarmasCapo/New_Create_Operation_0] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Did anyone faced this issue in past. Please let me know how to fix it.

Please comment if this information is not sufficient.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tested your server side SOAP UI service using SOAP UI?  This would at least verfiy that the server side works in any instance.

Comment: 1. make sure your Java program is creating a correct request, and the body is not null. 2. make sure the wsdl you are using in your java application is up-to-date.

Comment: I have tested the mocked service from soap ui and it works fine. Also  as I said earlier request is formed correctly by the Java client and same  wsdl is used in both the places.

Comment: How request header is a problem. Its correct. The issue is `<soap:body/>` is empty. @Henry

Comment: @amit4497 yes, sorry; deleted.